# How center text of the column headers in SlickGrid?

Tags: center, slickgrid

there any way to center text in a column header
Any ideas how to do this or what  ccs  must be changed ?

Answer (score 9):

Add the following style in your css:

```
.slick-header-column {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want all column headers to be aligned the same way, you can also define individual css classes via the `headerCssClass` attribute of a [column definition](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Column-Options), like:

```
var columns = [
    {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title", headerCssClass: 'text'},
    {id: "price", name: "Price", field: "price", headerCssClass: 'currency'}
];
```

and:

```
.slick-header-column.currency {
    text-align: center;
}
```